# Authentication redirection to login page on IdentityServer

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect

I have IdentityServer 4 and an MVC application that gets the identity from IdentityServer. Everything works fine.

My question is why do I have to login on IdentityServer and not on the MVC project?

I would prefer to stay in my MVC project, instead of being redirected to IdentityServer and back to my MVC project. Can somebody please explain why it has to work like that?

The redirects takes time, are not instant, and creates a lot of traffic that is unnecessary. I understand this redirection when there is an external provider like Facebook, but in my case I think it is useless.

And is it possible with IdentityServer 4 to login/create user on the Mvc app and call the api functions from IS4 server for Login/Create User?

Comment: I think you need to review why you decided to use IdentityServer in the first place if you wish to implement your own login - might as well use normal ASP.NET Authentication features if you have no use for the tokens or the security an idsrv provides.

Comment: I didn't say I want to implement my own login. I asked why we cannot use a local window (from the mvc project) instead to be redirected back and forth. And I use the tokens provided by IS4 to authenticate against my WEB APi.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you don't like is just a protocol. The protocol called OpenId Connect. And Identity Server just implements that protocol. The idea is that only Identity Provider itself can authenticate a user secure enough. 
There is a workaround called [*Resource Owner password flow or grant*](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/resource_owner.html), where you ask a user for credentials in you client app and then transfer that credentials to IdP. The flow is not recommended for general use, but you may use it whenever you own both client app and IdP.  
One more possible solution for you (in case you own the only app and by some, really strange, reason would like to use Identity Server as an IdP) is to host Identity Server inside of your app. Then using [`IdentityServerTools`](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/tools.html?highlight=IdentityServerTools) helper class you can access the IdSrv internals without network calls.
You can find much more information on both these approaches in Identity Server Docs and [OpenId Connect specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html).